# Rmarkdown output to word creates one table instead of two

Tags: r, ms-word, rstudio, knitr

**Rmarkdown output to word creates one table instead of two**

The code below is expected to create two independent tables when I knit a Word document using Rmarkdown in Rstudio, but instead it creates one combined table.

Code expected to create a word document with two tables:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: word_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

## R Markdown


```{r}
knitr::kable(head(iris))
```


```{r}
knitr::kable(head(iris))
```
````

But it only creates one:

[image]

If, however, I set echo=TRUE, I get the expected two tables. When I output the same document to HTML it also creates the expected two tables. 
The tables are created by clicking the knit-button in Rstudio.

The question is: How do I get two tables, instead of one?

To clarify: the problem is not that two tables are created with little space between them. The problem is that *one* table is created. On the picture attached to this question, it indeed appears to be two tables (because there are two headers), but it is actually *one* table. But the answer by Axeman solves this. I still believe this is a bug though, because in earlier versions of knitr it was not necessary to specify `<br><br>` between tables, to ensure that they were not combined into one.

I filed a bug-report, but no one has seen it:
https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115008683128-Bug-Two-tables-produced-by-knitr-kable-are-rendered-as-one-in-word-output

```
Rstudio version 1.0.153

> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Danish_Denmark.1252  LC_CTYPE=Danish_Denmark.1252    LC_MONETARY=Danish_Denmark.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=Danish_Denmark.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] compiler_3.4.1  backports_1.1.0 magrittr_1.5    rprojroot_1.2   htmltools_0.3.6 tools_3.4.1     yaml_2.1.14     Rcpp_0.12.12    rmarkdown_1.6   stringi_1.1.5  
[11] highr_0.6       knitr_1.16      digest_0.6.12   stringr_1.2.0   evaluate_0.10.1
```

On my machine at home I do not have this problem. So the same code produces independent tables, without needing to put `<br><br>` between the chunks. On this home machine the sessioninfo is this:

```
R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] compiler_3.4.1  backports_1.1.0 magrittr_1.5    rprojroot_1.2   htmltools_0.3.6 tools_3.4.1     yaml_2.1.14     Rcpp_0.12.12   
 [9] stringi_1.1.5   rmarkdown_1.6   knitr_1.17      stringr_1.2.0   digest_0.6.12   evaluate_0.10.1
```

Comment: There's no question here.

Comment: Thanks, updated to clarify the question.

Comment: Thanks. I will put it elsewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put an HTML comment in between, and you get a more clear separation between your tables.

E.g.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: word_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

## R Markdown

```{r}
knitr::kable(head(iris))
```

<!-- -->

```{r}
knitr::kable(head(iris))
```
````

If this fails, you can put a newline instead, replace `<!-- -->` with `<br><br>`.

Comment: Solved thanks. Now I get two tables, instead of one. To clarify: The problem was not too little space between the tables, but that I actually only got one table. That one table *looked* like two separate tables, because it had two headers (rows with bold text), but it was actually only one. This only becomes evident when you try to move it around inside MS Word.

Comment: Instead of `<br><br>`, which actually has a meaning (line breaks), I recommend you to use a comment `<!-- -->` to separate the two tables. This is not a bug of knitr. It is an issue from Pandoc but not a bug, either. The HTML comment trick is common in Pandoc, e.g. see the section "Ending a list" in the manual: http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#ending-a-list The situation here is similar: you have to have something between the two tables to end the first table.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @Yihui! Feel free to post your own answer or edit mine.

Comment: <!-- -->, does not work one my machine, i still get only one table. But <br><br> *does* work.